# silverlight, how to implement a property of type StoryBoard

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have a user control and I want to create a property of type storyboard which I can set in xaml, so I tried to following, but I get a bad property error when I run it:

```
private Storyboard sbTransitionIn_m;
public Storyboard TransitionIn
{
    get {return sbTransitionIn_m;}
    set {sbTransitionIn_m = value;}
}
```

xaml:

```
<MyStuff:MyUserControl x:Name="ctlTest" TransitionIn="sbShow"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the storyboard in Resources and then refer it as staticresource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <Storyboard x:Key="sbShow">
     <!--  -->
   </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<MyStuff:MyUserControl x:Name="ctlTest" TransitionIn="{StaticResource sbShow}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard can't serialize from a string attribute like that.  Try this:

```
<MyStuff:MyUserControl x:Name="ctlTest">
    <MyStuff:MyUserControl.TransitionIn>
        <Storyboard/>
    </MyStuff:MyUserControl.TransitionIn>
</MyStuff:MyUserControl>
```